# Warning Symbol inside the password field of the logon screen in Centos linux 7

Tags: linux, centos, login-screen

OS: Centos 7

There is a warning symbol inside the password field of the logon screen of my Centos 7 server[image: Login picture]
that doesn't let my enter my desktop, even when I write the correct password.

What is my problem?
What does this symbol mean?

EDIT1:
I can login through SSH.

EDIT2: I enable the "Show text" option for the password field, just to be sure that my password was correct, but I still can't login

EDIT3: I try to disable and enable caps lock.

EDIT 4: this is what is written in /var/log/secure when I try lo login:

```
Mar 20 16:47:40 mainserver unix_chkpwd[38488]: password check failed for user (admin)
Mar 20 16:47:40 mainserver gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=admin
Mar 20 16:47:40 mainserver gdm-password]: gkr-pam: the password for the login keyring was invalid.
```

EDIT5: I am using teamviewer.

EDIT6: I reboot the server, it seems it was a temporary bug, because I don't have the problem anymore. Not sure what was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just keys issue, enter the above command and check if the keyboard layout is the same for X11 & VC :

```
localectl status
```

**EDIT :**

Last things i will suggest.

1- It is possible that **local** access is not permitted , check the content of '/etc/security/access.conf'.

2- Make sure that **selinux** is disabled :

```
getenforce
```

3- Check "/etc/securetty" whether it contains console :

```
cat /etc/securetty
```

4- Publish the content of "/etc/pam.d/login" & try to gather logs through by *' tail -f /var/log/messages' 'tail -f /var/log/secure*' when trying to login.
/etc/pam.d/login

4- If the issue is not solved, then reinstall GNOME or the whole OS.

**EDIT 2 :**

Since the published logs on '/var/log/secure', i suggest to :

1- Check the content of '/etc/pam.d/password-auth', 'auth' lines should contain the above  per default :

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

2- Check and repair permissions on 'unix_chkpwd' :

```
ls -ltr /sbin/unix_chkpwd
## It should be '-rwsr-xr-x.'
chmod u+s /sbin/unix_chkpwd
```

3- It could be possibly a temporary bug, so try to reboot the system or to reinstall/update GNOME as i suggested recently :

```
## Install
yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"
## UPDATE
yum groupupdate 'X Window System' GNOME 'GNOME Applications' 'GNOME Desktop'
```

4- If none of these solutions worked, report it as bug.

Comment: Is not the same, this is the output inside an ssh session:
[admin@mainserver log]$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us

Comment: Where is that ?

Comment: No, this is a physical host.

Comment: The warning icon means that  capslock is activated.

Comment: Try to gather logs through by ' tail -f /var/log/messages & tail -f  /var/log/secure' when trying to login.